# React Material-UI Grid Layout not working as Expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styling

I am making a react app and it has a basic layout that has a Navbar, a SidePanel (that contain some Action Buttons), and the Content area. [Click here to see the expected layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSnIj.png)

I coded this using Grid Layout in Material UI but my **Side-Panel is overlapping the Navbar.** [Click here to see what I am getting as output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVdfc.png)

([You can also see https://localhost:3000 output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naO92.png))

I tried to inspect it in my Browser but I was unable to find the bug. I think I am missing something which I am unable to figure out.

**Here is my App.js** which defines the basic Layout of app. (Please ignore the extra code and see the return statement as rest is useless in solving this issue)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Home from "./components/pages/Home"
import About from './components/pages/About';
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch}from 'react-router-dom';
import Error from './components/pages/Error';
import AddBooking from './components/Bookings/AddBooking';
import EditBooking from './components/Bookings/EditBooking';
import ViewBooking from './components/Bookings/ViewBooking';
import Bookings from './components/pages/Bookings';
import Booking2 from './components/pages/Booking2';
import Login from './components/pages/login';
import fire from './fire';
import SidePanel from './components/layout/SidePanel';
import {Grid} from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
    

    const[user, setUser]= useState('');
    const[email, setEmail]= useState('');
    const[password, setPassword]= useState('');
    const[emailError, setEmailError]= useState('');
    const[passwordError, setPasswordError]= useState('');
    const[hasAccount, setHasAccount]= useState(false);

    const clearInputs=()=>{
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
    }

    const clearErrors=()=>{
        setEmailError('');
        setPasswordError('');
    }

    const handleLogin=()=>{
        clearErrors();
        fire
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .catch((err)=>{                             
            switch(err.code){
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                case "auth/user-disabled":
                case "auth/user-not-found":
                    setEmailError(err.message);
                    break;
                case "auth/wrong-password":
                    setPasswordError(err.message);
                    break;
            }
        });
    };

    const handleSignup=()=>{
        clearErrors();
        fire
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .catch((err)=>{                             
            switch(err.code){
                case "auth/email-already-in-use":
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                    setEmailError(err.message);
                    break;
                case "auth/weak-password":
                    setPasswordError(err.message);
                    break;
            }
        });
    };

    const handleLogout=()=>{
        fire.auth().signOut();
    };

    const authListener=()=>{
        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
            if(user){
                clearInputs();
                setUser(user);
            }else{
                setUser("");
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        authListener();
    }, []);

  
    return (

    <Router>
        {user?(
            <div>
            <Grid container direction="column">
                <Grid item>
                    <Navbar />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item container>
                    <Grid item xs={false} sm={2}>
                        <SidePanel />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={10}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                            <Route exact path="/Bookings" component={Bookings}/>
                            <Route exact path="/Booking2" component={Booking2}/>
                            <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
                            <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                            <Route exact path="/Bookings/add" component={AddBooking}/>
                            <Route exact path="/Bookings/edit/:id" component={EditBooking}/>
                            <Route exact path="/Bookings/view/:id" component={ViewBooking}/>
                            <Route component={Error}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            </div>
        ):(
            <Login 
            email={email} 
            setEmail={setEmail}
            password={password}
            setPassword={setPassword}
            handleLogin={handleLogin}
            handleSignup={handleSignup}
            hasAccount={hasAccount}
            setHasAccount={setHasAccount}
            emailError={emailError}
            passwordError={passwordError}
            clearInputs={clearInputs}
            clearErrors={clearErrors}
            />
        )}
    </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Add  `margin-top` to your `SiderBar`.

Comment: Yes that can be a solution but its temporary as I want layout to be as expected. Giving margin is not ideal solution as layout is still wrong. (We have just modified it). Please refer to the question again as I have made it more clear by adding expected result and output.

Comment: Without having a runnable example it will be really hard to examine the problem. But you could try having `zIndex` with the combination of `height` it should work. But as I said its hard for us to give you a 100% solution without a runnable example.

Comment: The issue is solved. There was a class which was over-writing the css of App.js. It has been resolved.